# Openstack Opendaylight L3 issue

Tags: openstack, opendaylight, openstack-neutron

I am having an issue with ODL + OpenStack + OVS L3 routing. I had a previous installation of OVS + OpenStack operational with one control node and one compute/network node.

After installing Open daylight and following the instructions on the Opendaylight site for Netvirt integration, I have L2 working on the VXLAN, but any router that I deploy has all interfaces down.

I cleared the OVS config and allowed ODL to create the BR-INT bridge, and then I added a mapping for :. Is there anything else I need to as I understand that you do not need to create BR-EX if ODL is being used.

Within the neutron.conf I have specified odl-router.

Let me know if you want to see any configurations I am at a bit of a loss here.

Cheers

Comment: This looks like a service config issue and not a coding issue. Is there a [mcve] that highlights your issue?